# XFS Quota issue in Ubuntu 20

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-20.04

I was trying to enable XFS quota in / partition [Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS]. I have added following in /etc/fstab and tried rebooting server.

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/1234aa7f-6422-41c0-1239-11123b5f2ca2 / xfs uquota,gquota 0 0
```

But when server comes online / partition  still show noquota.

```
# cat /proc/mounts | grep ' / '
/dev/sda4 / xfs rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota 0 0
```

Is there any bootime settings causing this problem? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself.

> Turning on quotas on the root filesystem is slightly different from
> the above.  For  Linux XFS, the quota mount flags must be passed in
> with the "rootflags=" boot parameter.

So I have modified /etc/default/grub as follows.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rootflags=usrquota,grpquota"
```

Then updated grub conf

```
# update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-90-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-90-generic
done
```

After reboot could see quota is enabled.

```
# cat /proc/mounts | grep ' / '
/dev/sda4 / xfs rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,usrquota,grpquota 0 0
```